# Why does my relationship return results but not "withCount"?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model which has a relationship with "where" and "if". I need to retrieve all the models where the count of the relationship is > 1.

When I try to get it with "withCount", I end up having models which have relationships having 0 to the "shared_job_offers_count" when they should have 1. However, it works properly for some model.

I noticed that it happens when the "$this->isSubscribedPremium()" in the "if" is true.

```
RELATIONSHIP

    public function shared_job_offers() {
        if($this->isSubscribedPremium()) {
            return $this->hasMany('App\JobOffer')->where('disable_share', false);
        } else {
            return $this->hasMany('App\JobOffer')->where('manual_share', true);
        }
    }

RETRIEVING THE RESULTS
App\Employer::withCount('shared_job_offers')->get()->where('shared_job_offers_count', '>', 0)
```

RECAP:

withCount returns 0 for some models, 1 for the others
it returns 0 mainly when "$this->isSubscribedPremium()" is true
i can get all the proper relationships if I just retrieve it directly.

Any idea?

Comment: @TimLewis I get "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'shared_job_offers_count"

Comment: Ah, there it is: `App\Employer::withCount('shared_job_offers')->has('shared_job_offers', '>', 1)->get();`. That should return only `Employer` records with `shared_job_offers` relationship count of 1 or more.